# How to get value of an exponential with imaginary part?

Tags: complex-numbers, quaternions

A quaternion is written as: [image: q=a+bi+cj+dk] where `a,b,c,d` are all real numbers. However, `a` identifies the real part of the quaterion, while the imaginary part of the quaterion is the combination of `i,j and k`. These three parts (`i,j,k`) are orthogonal to each other and satisfy the following relationship:

[image: i^{2}=j^{2}=k^{2}=ijk=-1]

[image: ij=k]

[image: jk=i]

[image: ik=j]

Another representation of quaternions is amplitude phase representation, which can be expressed as:

[image: q=|q|e^{phii}e^{thetaj}e^{psi*k}]

where `|q| is the amplitude` of q, and `phi, theta, psi are the phase angle` of q

Now, if I would like to get the imaginary parts from this last equation, could I take [image: e^{phi}e^{theta}e^{psi}] ? Is it right?

Comment: How do this relate to statistics? And what do it has to do with exponential families?

Comment: Can I post only questions related to statistics? It is related to exponential families because e^(phi*i)e^(theta*j)e^(psi*k) are exponential numbers, so the question is pretty related to exponential numbers.

Comment: Statistics *taken in a wide meaning*, including probabiliy and machine learning ... but exponential families is a very specific statistical concept, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320746/definition-of-family-of-a-distribution  : A specific kind of family of probability distributions!